# Is it possible to programmatically create a symbolic link on an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, symlink

I need to create a symbolic link on iPhone devices programatically in order to avoid a lot of slow file copying. Is this possible to do and if so, how?

Answer (score 5):

It's technically possible, via the [NSFileManager](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class. Grab the singleton instance and then use any of the calls listed under 'Linking an Item' or 'Symbolic-Link Operations' ([`createSymbolicLinkAtPath:withDestinationPath:error:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/createSymbolicLinkAtPath%3awithDestinationPath%3aerror%3a) looks like a good candidate).

Using a link rather than a direct file was a method briefly used by developers to update their Default.png programmatically, but that specific use has been outlawed by Apple. Besides that I'm afraid I have to plead ignorance on any SDK usage restrictions.